# How Do I determine if an Item Receipt was With Or Without a Bill in QBFC Response Set

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I was looking through the SDK information for ItemReceiptQuery to see if I can request receipts entered without bills.  Sorry, I am VERY new to the Quickbooks SDK. I am unable to find a filter to differentiate the two.

Some guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item Receipts are used to timely record inventory when the Bill hasn't been received.

If an Item Receipt has been create and then the Bill is received, the user just checks a box on the receipt and QB turns it into a Bill.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the fact that Item Receipts is only used when a bill is not there. Now I understand I was over thinking the issue.